# Picker renderer for iOS Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, uipickerview

[image]

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms programming. Would like to customize/change the way the Picker

In the picture:
-Button with the text 'Select', when clicked calls picker.Focus()
-Picker with both black background and text colors behind the select button
-Empty ListView
-The picker options wheel pane, pops up when a picker is 'Focused'

Picker implementation code:

```
Picker picker = new Picker
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    WidthRequest = 73,
    HeightRequest = 25,
    BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
    TextColor = Color.Black
};

List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("OPTIONS 1");
myList.Add("OPTIONS 2");
myList.Add("OPTIONS 3");
myList.Add("OPTIONS 4");
myList.Add("OPTIONS 5");

foreach (string str in myList)
{
    picker.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Code customizes the 'box' that a user clicks to bring the picker options wheel pane into view, but doesn't (or at least appear to) offer any options for customizing the picker pane.

How to place the picker wheel pop-up pane inside of the ListView?
How to change font size of the options inside the picker wheel and change the height of the pane displaying the options?

tl;dr - How to change picker pane height, item font size, pane placement?

This is as far as I've gotten...

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using AppName.iOS;
using AppName;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPicker), typeof(MyPickerRenderer))]
namespace AppName.iOS
{
    public class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Configure the native control and subscribe to event handlers
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The picker wheel in iOS called `UIPickerView` we can get this contol in renderer like:

```
UITextField textField = Control;
UIPickerView pickerView = textField.InputView as UIPickerView;
```

Then we can customize this just as what you want using `Delegate`.

Firstly we should get the `dataSource` in your case we can get it like:

```
Picker myPicker = Element;
itemList = myPicker.Items.ToList();
```

Secondly create the delegate and set the list as parameter:

```
pickerView.Delegate = new MyPickerViewDelegate(itemList);

public class MyPickerViewDelegate: UIPickerViewDelegate
{

    List<string> itemList;

    public MyPickerViewDelegate(List<string> list)
    {
        itemList = list;
    }
}
```

At last we can begin customizing with the events below:

```
//Define the Font size or style
public override NSAttributedString GetAttributedTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
{
    var text = new NSAttributedString(
        itemList[(int)row],
        font: UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(24),
        foregroundColor: UIColor.Red,
        strokeWidth: 4
    );

    return text;
}
//Define the row height
public override nfloat GetRowHeight(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
{
    return 80;
}
```

Moreover if you want to customize more flexible(including placement), you can use following method:

```
public override UIView GetView(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component, UIView view)
{
    UIView contentView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width, 80));

    UILabel label = new UILabel();
    label.Frame = contentView.Bounds;
    contentView.AddSubview(label);

    label.Text = itemList[(int)row];
    //Change the label style
    label.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(24);
    label.TextColor = UIColor.Red;

    return contentView;
}
```

Here is my custom renderer for you referring to:

```
public class MyPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
{
    List<string> itemList;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Picker myPicker = Element;
        itemList = myPicker.Items.ToList();

        UITextField textField = Control;
        UIPickerView pickerView = textField.InputView as UIPickerView;
        pickerView.Delegate = new MyPickerViewDelegate(itemList);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can follow your class implementation, but I'm new to Xamarin.Forms, I don't understand where the first five lines of code go. The 'Control' assignment to textField, are Control assignments only valid in functions? (Control is seen in the 'OnElementChanged' method in the original post). Picker = Element surely is referencing my own picker assignment? If it is then I still don't understand how Control is to be used.

Comment: @jtth You can put them in `OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)`

Comment: @jtth I have updated my answer, post my renderer. Please see it above.

Comment: Yes thank you, I have the text how I would like it now, but I was hoping this would as well manipulate the wheel pane pop ups placement and/or be able to adjust its height. Is that possible with this renderer?

Comment: @jtth Maybe, I think you'd better post a new thread. Specify the requirement more details. Let's analyze how to achieve it.

Comment: Done. Provided photoshopped examples to clarify my intention.

Comment: @jtth Sorry, I can’t understand your requirement from your description. You want which part to adjust its height?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create your own implementation of the a `UiPickerView`. That will allow you to set the font size using [this guide](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/260233/#Comment_260233) or this one. As for the height and placement; it appears that you can [set the placement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069877/5209435) but the height is a bit more difficult and I can only find examples in objective C or swift.

Best of luck!

Comment: Unfortunately I forgot to include the 'iOS' tag in the op. *Edit: All three of your provided links deal with Android picker renderers. As well the blog post deals with the height of the picker entry field(s), not the picker wheel pane that pops up.

Comment: @jtth I have added iOS links to my answer.

Comment: How about https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/123491/#Comment_123491 or https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/260233/#Comment_260233